# Product Method Overloading

Tags: java, overloading

so I was working on this problem on CodeHS, then I was stuck for so long so decided to ask here.

The exercise is to overload the product method to allow for multiplying together other types of values:

1. two doubles
2. an int and a double
3. a double and an int
4. three ints
5. three doubles

   ```
   public class Product extends ConsoleProgram
   {
       public void run()
       {
           int intValue = 5;
           double doubleValue = 2.5;

           int product1 = product(intValue, intValue);
           System.out.println(product1);

           // Use method overloading to define methods 
           // for each of the following method calls

           double product2 = product(doubleValue, doubleValue);
           System.out.println(product2);

           int product3 = product(intValue, intValue, intValue);
           System.out.println(product3);

           double product4 = product(intValue, doubleValue);
           System.out.println(product4);

           double product5 = product(doubleValue, intValue);
           System.out.println(product5);

           double product6 = product(doubleValue, doubleValue, doubleValue);
           System.out.println(product6);
       }

       public int product(int one, int two)
       {
           return one * two;
       }
   }
   ```

Thank you

Comment: *I was stuck for so long*. On what exactly? I see no evidence that you've made any effort.

Comment: You should have first search how to overload methods in Java. Seems to me you made no efforts.

Comment: @cdadiga Yes, I have done research and I still could not understand and I have spent time coding but it kept showing me error msg so I just decided to reset the code as it will be easy for you guys to explain. Sorry it seemed like I was just asking for answers without any effort.

Answer (score 3):

be aware that overloading means, the name of the method and the return type remains the same as the original/ initial method.

then you need to define/ implement those methods>

2 doubles would be:

```
public int product(double one, double two)
{
    return (int)(one * two);
}
```

an int and a double would be

```
public int product(int one, double two)
{
    return (int)(one * two);
}
```

etc

Comment: what do you mean with fixed type @information_interchange?

Comment: sometimes you get an int back, other times a double

Comment: overloading means same method name same return type but taking different parameters....

Comment: that is why the method returns always an int ....even if you give doubles as paramters

Comment: Thank you so much, I just did not get the concept of method overloading even after reading and watching youtube vids. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Method overloading means you can create methods with same method name by changing those methods parameters (parameter count,parameter type and parameter Patterns). Combination of method name and parameters also called as **method signature**

Following is an example for method overloading.

```
public void int myMethod(){} 

public void int myMethod(int a){} 

public void String myMethod(String a){} 

public void double myMethod(int a , String a){} 

public void int myMethod(String a,int a){}
```

**Note that you can't overload methods by changing return type**

Answer (score 0):

for all yall looking for codehs answers heres a working piece of code

```java
 public class Product extends ConsoleProgram{
     public void run(){
        int intValue = 5;
        double doubleValue = 2.5;
        
        int product1 = product(intValue, intValue);
        System.out.println(product1);
        
        // Use method overloading to define methods 
        // for each of the following method calls
        
        double product2 = product(doubleValue, doubleValue);
        System.out.println(product2);
        
        int product3 = product(intValue, intValue, intValue);
        System.out.println(product3);
        
        double product4 = product(intValue, doubleValue);
        System.out.println(product4);
        
        double product5 = product(doubleValue, intValue);
        System.out.println(product5);
        
        double product6 = product(doubleValue, doubleValue, doubleValue);
        System.out.println(product6);
    }
    
    public int product(int one, int two){
        return (int)(one * two);
    }
    public double product(double one, double two){
        return (double)(one * two);
    }
    public double product(int one, double two){
        return (double)(one * two);
    }
    public int product(int one, int two, int three){
        return (int)(one * two * three);
    }
    public double product(double one, double two, double three){
        return (double)(one * two * three);
    }
    public double product(double one, int two){
        return (double)(one * two);
    }
}
```